# What is the impact of react-native-skia on the size of the final bundle?

Tags: react-native, skia

I am super excited about the possibilities which bring [react-native-skia](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/) package. However, I haven't found any information about how it influences the production bundle size and bootstrap speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer in the updated [documentation](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/getting-started/bundle-size).
The package adds 6 MB to the IOS bundle and 4 MB to Android.